# How to implement replicate a table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, replication

I have a table as *table1* and another table as *table2*.
Now *table1* and *table2* are having the same structure.
Any modifications in *table1* should automatically reflect in *table2*.

Please suggest me some solutions..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be a set of OnInsert, OnUpdate and OnDelete triggers.  However is the intention that this data is an exact copy of Table1 just to be accessed with a different name?  If so, I recommend that you create a view instead of duplicating the data.

Comment: Thank you. The main intention behind is we have two applications accessing the same table.one inserts or updates the table and the other reads.But there are too many hits on this table.So,I thought i could use 2 identical tables one for each application.When one application writes any data it must be reflected on the other table from which other application reads the data.

Comment: I just got a solution.I tried replication in sql server 2005.I dont know its effect on the performance and other tables.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28951/SQL-Server-2005-Merge-Replication-Step-by-Step-Pro

Comment: Replication isn't really meant for two tables on the same server.  This is meant for multiple distributed databases and/or a online backup via things like log shipping.  If you have too many hits to one table perhaps you need to look at the indexing and the queries being run on the table, or the design of your app.  Partitioning sounds like a better fit for what you are trying to achieve.